# Video.JS - Multiple events firing on exact time once

Tags: javascript, events, video, video.js

I'm developing a web application in which I've got a video element. This, as I've had good experiences with it, is controlled via the [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) scripts.

However, on my app, there are some points in which the video needs to be paused until played by the user (or by a script, it's not relevant), but not after.

## What I have

Basically - and the basic information you need - what I have is an array of items, let's say `item_array`, with objects in it. Each object has an `id`, a `media` object with some information of it, including a `src`, and an `indications` array - which would be the pause-times objects. Something like that:

```
var items_array = [
    {
        id: 1234,
        media: {
            id: 2345,
            src: 'video_source.mp4',
            duration: 302.56
        },
        indications: [
            {
                id: 1, 
                time: 65.380
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                time: 89.238
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                time: 123.765
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Of course, I've got the `video` variable, which stores the VideoJS reference and is accessible all along the code as a global variable (maybe it's useful for you to know that).

## What I need

Basically, I need to be able to load a video source and tell the script that the video must pause at 1:05.380, 1:29.238 and 2:03.765, for example.

Once paused, the user can play the video again, and it will not be paused (at least, by the script) again until the next time mark is reached.

Then, the user can specify a new video to load, with its new pause-points, so old pause-points should be removed and new ones set.

Also, it would be necessary to perform other actions apart from pausing the video (such as showing a message, etc.). But it's not necessary for you to know any of these - just I have to be able to write some actions to do on every pause-point.

## What I've tried

Well, I've been playing with `timeupdate`. The first problem is that this only fires every now and then, so `video.currentTime() == NN.NNN` will not always work.

The script `video.currentTime() >= NN.NNN` is not possible neither, because the user must be able to play further the pause-time (yes, the event can be set off once reached, but if the user skips it on the time line, the video must not be paused).

So, if the pause-time is at 1:05 and the user skips from 0:45 to 1:25, the pause-time set to 1:05 must not be triggered, thus the video must not be paused - so the line written before does not work as I'd like to.

**Thank you everyone in advance for your time and help!** If you need any further information, please ask me and I will submit it as soon as I can!

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've come up with a possible solution. Sure it's not the best in performance, but it does what it's meant to.

I write it here and maybe someone will find it useful.

## The solution

What I do is to fire a custom event everytime the `timeupdate` event is triggered, so I can delete all actions attached to this custom event without breaking VideoJS default event actions.

Then, I set a `time_range`, so I can make the comparison between `video.currentTime()` with the desired `indication.time` without being exact, but with some space to happen.

Finally, when it happens, I pause the video (and show the indication, those actions I told you I needed to do) and set a new property of the indication, `has_shown` to `true`.

At every `custom_timeupdate` I check if the `video.currentTime()` is inside that space of time I told you and if that `indication.has_shown` is set to `false`. If so, the process triggers. If not, nothing happens (so if an indication has already been shown it does not pause the video again).

But, as I wanted it to show it again if the user returned to that point, I set a last check so if `video.currentTime()` is - a little bit - far from that point, the property `has_shown` is set to `false` again.

This is done, of course, for every `indication` we have.

Here you have the code:

```
var time_range = 0.125

video.on("timeupdate", function(){
    video.trigger("indications_timeupdate")
})

function load_indications(indications){
    /* 
        Function actions ...
    */

    // If the video is defined, as we are loading them new, we set off old Indication timers
    if(video !== undefined) video.off("indications_timeupdate")

    $.each(indications, function(i, ind){
        video.on("indications_timeupdate", function(){
            if(video.currentTime() >= ind.time - time_range && video.currentTime() <= ind.time + time_range && !ind.has_shown){
                video.pause()
                ind.has_shown = true
            }else if(video.currentTime() >= ind.time + time_range || video.currentTime() <= ind.time - time_range){
                ind.has_shown = false
            }
        })
    })
}
```

As I said, maybe it's not the best solution, but it's the best one that I've been able to think of.

Thank you for your time to everyone who has tried to think of an approach for this question!

Best regards.

Comment: The `time_range` is set to this value because from what I've researched, the max. time a browser waits to trigger the `timeupdate` event on HTML5 video is 250ms for Chrome and Safari, so as it's a window from before and after, it should be half of it: `0.125`.